PDFjs-dist Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
I built a pdf-viewer as a component using React.
In the component, I imported pdfjs-dist like this.
import { getDocument, GlobalWorkerOptions } from 'pdfjs-dist';
GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL('/pdf.worker.min.mjs', import.meta.url).toString();

In vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      target: 'es2015',
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/PdfViewer/index.js'),
      name: 'PdfViewer',
      fileName: () => 'pdfViewer.js',
      formats: ['umd'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'pdfjs-dist': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/pdfjs-dist'),
    },
  },
  esbuild: {
    loader: 'jsx',
    include: /.*\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: []
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['pdfjs-dist'],
    esbuildOptions: {
      target: 'es2015',
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  },
})

I build the component in production mode.
If I import the above pdfViewer then I will get the following error
../pdfViewer.js 12928:23-48
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

How can I resolve this?
I appreciate any help you can provide.
